# POST запрос в java

Tags: java, android, post, okhttp

Как отправить на сервер ответ в таком формате на java(Android studio)?

```
POST
        Array
        (
            [login] => test
            [sess_passw] => dc3d79597eb2a37fc5300f85542266fa
            [project_id] => 77      
            [date_interview] => 2017-01-22 14:57:41
            [cell] => 
            [answers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4648
                [duration_time_question] => 0
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4650
                [duration_time_question] => 0
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [answer_id] => 4667
                [duration_time_question] => 1
                [text_open_answer] => 
            )
```

Comment: причём тут php?

Comment: Я прилагаю кусочек кода, аналогичные данные должны быть получены на сервере, это php.

Comment: Ни чё непонятно. В чём суть вопроса то? как отправить запрос на java? или как получить ответ на php?

Comment: Как отправить пост запрос в таком формате на языке java. Уже разобрал отправу и получение, но там был другой формат, просто ключ-значение (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619753/Как-получить-ответ-из-post-запроса?noredirect=1#comment860491_619753), а здесь массив

Comment: так и отправляйте ` "test[][]","test"` на сервер придёт `array(array('test'))` php метка тут не к чему

Comment: @Naumov Понял, большое спасибо

Comment: Сформировали то запрос?